# Problem with getting alerts from the TradingView strategy

Tags: pine-script, alert, webhooks, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I want to modernize the TradingView strategy code to send alerts **Open Long** and **Open Short** to a specific **WebHook** address with a **Once Per Bar Close** trigger. But I encountered a problem.

When I use **"comment"** in **"strategy.entry"** and in the alert box I write **{{strategy.order.alert_message}}**, I get an **ID** message.

When I type **"alert_message"**, an error pops up when I try to compile the code:

```
Unknown argument `alert_message`;
Cannot call `strategy.entry` with arguments (literal__string, bool, literal__string, string); available overloads: strategy.entry(literal__string, series__bool, series, series, series, string, literal__string, string, series__bool) => void
```

Code of a strategy:
**https://pastebin.com/4SeQj3Sg**

Comment: Upgrade your code to v5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert_message` has been introduced in `v4` so you should upgrade your code.

This is the signature in `v3`:

```
strategy.entry(id, long, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type, comment, when) → void
```

You can use [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html) guideline.